# Are there logs to see git commands from bundler?

Tags: ruby, git, bundler

I am using `bundle install` to install some Ruby gems from a mix of public and private git repos.

The issue is that after one particular gem is installed through git, the local directory is polluted with that gem's source code. It's like the git repo has completely changed.

Is there a way to log all the git commands that bundler is running and to make sure it is putting the git repos of gems into the correct path?

1. add a new gem to Gemfile
2. run `bundle install`
3. check the README.markdown and it now has completely different text in it:

   ```
   # activerecord-import [![Build Status](https://travis-ci.org/zdennis/activerecord-import.svg?branch=master)](https://travis-ci.org/zdennis/activerecord-import)
   ```

To restore my repo, I run `git reflog` and then `git reset --hard` to get the right commit back. It looks like during bundle install, the git command run is doing a checkout of a particular branch that overwrites all of the files in my git repo.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). It sounds like you're having a bundler problem and you suspect that it's not "putting the git repos of gems into the correct path." If you describe that problem in detail you might get a more straightforward solution than poring over git logs.

Comment: I think you may be right @JordanRunning digging deeper into this and not seeing anyone else reporting this issue with bundler+git.

Comment: That's very strange. Is there a reason you're using it as a git dependency and not an ordinary rubygems dependency (`gem "activerecord-import"`)?

Comment: @JordanRunning it's listed in the Gemfile: `gem 'activerecord-import', '0.19.0', :git => 'git@github-private-repo:private-repo/activerecord-import.git', :ref => '10b18879201608f3ee83d0c4fd700e6f13ce021a'` that's why I'm very confused. thanks for the GIT_TRACE, it looks like nothing is amiss (bundle install with git seems to use git sub-modules and the gem causing issues is that last gem installed from git)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will help you solve your actual problem, but the answer to your question is that you can see all of the `git` commands being executed by setting the `GIT_TRACE` environment variable. On macOS, Linux, etc. that looks like `GIT_TRACE=1 bundle install`. The method will be different on Windows.

Here's the output for a brand new `Gemfile` with one dependency:

```
$ cat Gemfile
# frozen_string_literal: true
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem 'rack', git: 'https://github.com/rack/rack'

$ GIT_TRACE=1 bundle install
Fetching https://github.com/rack/rack
12:43:02.753769 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git clone https://github.com/rack/rack /Users/jordanr/.rbenv/gems/2.6.0/cache/bundler/git/rack-02d63969ed912ff0486a199e1ea3aa78127fbb67 --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet
12:43:02.800426 run-command.c:637       trace: run_command: unset GIT_DIR; ssh git@github.com 'git-upload-pack '\''rack/rack'\'''
12:43:06.059759 run-command.c:637       trace: run_command: git index-pack --stdin --fix-thin '--keep=fetch-pack 23789 on jordanr.local' --check-self-contained-and-connected
12:43:06.067881 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git index-pack --stdin --fix-thin '--keep=fetch-pack 23789 on jordanr.local' --check-self-contained-and-connected
12:43:06.945711 run-command.c:637       trace: run_command: git rev-list --objects --stdin --not --all --quiet
12:43:06.951101 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git rev-list --objects --stdin --not --all --quiet
12:43:06.974513 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --verify master
12:43:06.991681 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git fetch --force --quiet --tags /Users/jordanr/.rbenv/gems/2.6.0/cache/bundler/git/rack-02d63969ed912ff0486a199e1ea3aa78127fbb67
12:43:06.993341 run-command.c:637       trace: run_command: unset GIT_PREFIX; 'git-upload-pack '\''/Users/jordanr/.rbenv/gems/2.6.0/cache/bundler/git/rack-02d63969ed912ff0486a199e1ea3aa78127fbb67'\'''
12:43:07.000949 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git upload-pack /Users/jordanr/.rbenv/gems/2.6.0/cache/bundler/git/rack-02d63969ed912ff0486a199e1ea3aa78127fbb67
12:43:07.012806 run-command.c:637       trace: run_command: git rev-list --objects --stdin --not --all --quiet
12:43:07.022792 run-command.c:637       trace: run_command: git rev-list --objects --stdin --not --all --quiet
12:43:07.027701 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git rev-list --objects --stdin --not --all --quiet
12:43:07.034718 run-command.c:1553      run_processes_parallel: preparing to run up to 1 tasks
12:43:07.034753 run-command.c:1585      run_processes_parallel: done
12:43:07.034796 run-command.c:637       trace: run_command: git gc --auto --quiet
12:43:07.039832 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git gc --auto --quiet
12:43:07.050538 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git reset --hard 23580211825877c7ed3be5dd4f2996e67aa40a4e
12:43:07.074736 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git version
12:43:07.085179 git.c:659               trace: exec: git-submodule deinit --all --force
12:43:07.086081 run-command.c:637       trace: run_command: git-submodule deinit --all --force
12:43:07.124885 git.c:659               trace: exec: git-sh-i18n--envsubst --variables 'usage: $dashless $USAGE'
12:43:07.125490 run-command.c:637       trace: run_command: git-sh-i18n--envsubst --variables 'usage: $dashless $USAGE'
12:43:07.138222 git.c:659               trace: exec: git-sh-i18n--envsubst 'usage: $dashless $USAGE'
12:43:07.138930 run-command.c:637       trace: run_command: git-sh-i18n--envsubst 'usage: $dashless $USAGE'
12:43:07.158914 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --git-dir
12:43:07.166961 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --git-path objects
12:43:07.173881 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git rev-parse -q --git-dir
12:43:07.187418 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --show-prefix
12:43:07.193585 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --show-toplevel
12:43:07.203435 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git submodule--helper deinit --force --all
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Resolving dependencies...
Using bundler 2.0.1
Using rack 2.1.0 from https://github.com/rack/rack (at master@2358021)
Bundle complete! 1 Gemfile dependency, 2 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Comment: I think I figured out my issue and it looks like you were right. In the specific gem that's being checked out, the gemspec file has this line `\`git ls-files\`.split($\)`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue was with the gem and with bundler at one time recommending the usage of `git ls-files` to get the list of all files that belong to a gem for the gemspec file.

Changing gemspec.files to use Dir.glob appears to be the solution.

There's more info on the bundler github repo: https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/2287